# Set up PHPUnit with WordPress: The WordPress tests are 3 - 4 years old; does it matter?

Tags: testing, unit-tests

I'm trying to set up PHPUnit with WordPress, and the [tutorial](http://codesymphony.co/writing-wordpress-plugin-unit-tests/) I found tells me to download [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tests/trunk) repository so that I can bootstrap the WordPress environment to run my tests. The only issue I have is that the repo was last changed 3 - 4 years ago, which is a long time.

I have also googled a little but, and found a [guide](https://yoast.com/dev-blog/unit-testing-wordpress-plugins-with-phpunit-in-phpstorm/) for how to set up tests with PHPUnit in WebStorm, but that site were also linking to the same repo.

Does anyone have any experience using this, or using PHPUnit with WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be an old repo, you should use https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests. Obviously trunk should be used if you want to use the tests with 4.6. Not sure how much difference there is in the infrastructure between the version (in other words, it is unlikely that you care how core does a specific test, therefor the staleness of the core tests might not be an issue at all)

Comment: Having a bit of trouble finding the link to the svn repo from trac, though.

Comment: been awhile, but it is just in the general SVN, you can just navigate to locate the directory

Comment: or download all of the sources from here - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk?order=name bottom of the page include a link to a zip

Comment: Thanks, I just downloaded the zip. Might look into the svn option later.